# Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery While jQuery is already loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm facing an error with loading the `Bootstrap` library as it always gives this error:

> Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery

Despite that I'm attaching the `Bootstrap` library after making sure the `jQuery` is loaded but still getting the error.

I'm using the following code to attach the `jQuery` to the page by creating the element and append it to the `document`:

```
/******** Load jQuery if not present *********/
if (window.jQuery === undefined || window.jQuery.fn.jquery !== '3.1.1') {
    console.log("jQuery LOADED");
    var script_tag = document.createElement('script');
    script_tag.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
    script_tag.setAttribute("src",
        "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js");


    // Try to find the head, otherwise default to the documentElement
    (document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0] || document.documentElement).appendChild(script_tag);


    if (script_tag.readyState) {
        script_tag.onreadystatechange = function () { // For old versions of IE
            if (this.readyState == 'complete' || this.readyState == 'loaded') {
                console.log(window.jQuery.fn.jquery);
                scriptLoadHandler();
            }
        };
    } else {
        console.log("ONLOAD STATE");
        script_tag.onload = scriptLoadHandler;
    }
} else {
    // The jQuery version on the window is the one we want to use
    jQuery = window.jQuery;
    main();
}

function scriptLoadHandler() {
    // Restore $ and window.jQuery to their previous values and store the
    // new jQuery in our local jQuery variable
    jQuery = window.jQuery.noConflict(true);
    // Call our main function
    main();
}
```

Here I'm creating the `Bootstrap` after `document` is being ready:

```
function main() {

    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    var bootstrap_script = document.createElement('script');
    bootstrap_script.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
    bootstrap_script.setAttribute("src",
    "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js");

    (document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0] || document.documentElement).appendChild(bootstrap_script);
    })
}
```

Just to clarify a critical thing
I'm writing the `js` code in a separated `js` file, because I want to use later as a `jQuery plugin`. Thus, I'm trying to attach the libraries as I don't guarantee that the targeted page would include those libraries or not

Comment: "Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery version 1.9.1 or higher, but lower than version 4" but seems like this is not an issue of jquery version put your jquery before this function if not already done

Comment: @Curiousdev I already put the jQuery before this function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to load jquery using https

```
script_tag.setAttribute("src",
        "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js");
```

Hope it'll work.

Answer (score 4):

you have a missing ")}" in your "main" function. after correcting this, bootstrap loads successfully for me without giving any error. I'm using firefox 50.1.0

here is your code that works for me:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>document</title>
</head>
<body>

  <script>
    /******** Load jQuery if not present *********/
    if (window.jQuery === undefined || window.jQuery.fn.jquery !== '3.1.1') {
        console.log("jQuery LOADED");
        var script_tag = document.createElement('script');
        script_tag.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
        script_tag.setAttribute("src", "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js");

        // Try to find the head, otherwise default to the documentElement
        (document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0] || document.documentElement).appendChild(script_tag);

        if (script_tag.readyState) {
            script_tag.onreadystatechange = function () { // For old versions of IE
                if (this.readyState == 'complete' || this.readyState == 'loaded') {
                    console.log(window.jQuery.fn.jquery);
                    scriptLoadHandler();
                }
            };
        } else {
            console.log("ONLOAD STATE");
            script_tag.onload = scriptLoadHandler;
        }
    } else {
        // The jQuery version on the window is the one we want to use
        jQuery = window.jQuery;
        main();
    }

    function scriptLoadHandler() {
        // Restore $ and window.jQuery to their previous values and store the
        // new jQuery in our local jQuery variable
        jQuery = window.jQuery.noConflict(true);
        // Call our main function
        main();
    }

    function main() {
        jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        var bootstrap_script = document.createElement('script');
            bootstrap_script.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
            bootstrap_script.setAttribute("src",
        "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js");

            (document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0] || document.documentElement).appendChild(bootstrap_script);
        })
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks dear, actually it was my error in copying the code from my project as "})" is already there, anyways I've edited my question

Comment: I am happy to hear that my answer solve your problem

Comment: Dear my error is not solved yet, still facing the same problem, I've added the missing "})" to my code but that wasn't the cause of my problem

Comment: try to copy and paste the code in the snippet as it is. It works correctly for me, if it works for you, you can identify the error easily.

Comment: are the main function and the test for jQuery in the same file or in two separate files ?

Comment: I tried to copy it, it works fine but moving the codes to a separated `js` file will cause the error again, and this what I'm doing, all the `js` codes are written in a separated file as I want to use it as a jQuery plugin where I can't guarantee that the targeted page would include the jquery and the bootstrap libraries or not

Comment: @AbdelazizMokhnache yes both are in two separated files

Comment: I moved the test for jquery to a file named "test.js" and the main function to a file named "main.js" and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using a higher version. Use this version:

```
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js
```

Comment: Bootstrap v3.3.7 "dependencies": { "jquery": "1.9.1 - 3"}

Comment: Did you change `3.1.1` to `2.1.1` on both places

Comment: you know in `if` and while setting up the `src`

Comment: yeah sure I changed it on both places

Comment: i think this is not a solution for above Question. please make sure that it's work properly before answer any question @AnujaAgarwal

Comment: @SavaliyaRahul i agree with you this is not related to **Jquery Version**

Comment: @Curiousdev dear do you have any suggestion of what causes this issue?!

Comment: @AliAlhamaly did you tried above answer? in snippet it works cool and why this is not all about jquery version the reason behind this statement is if you open a [bootstrap js](https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js) there is a line **"Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery version 1.9.1 or higher, but lower than version 4"** and u have used version **3.1.1** so it's not about jquery version it's about u placed jquery where bootstrap not able to find this

Comment: @AliAlhamaly i have tried the same code on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7db59d86/) it works but i have to change jquery link with replace **http** to **https** try this may be it works :-(

Comment: @Curiousdev great!, your jsfiddle code works perfectly, despite that it seems the CSS library is not getting loaded also, will check how to overcome this other issue, anyways great thanks for you

Comment: okk i have answered below as well it's completely my pleasure to help you. :-) please mark answered as accepted if you find it's working

Answer (score 0):

Why make it so complicated?

Just add this inside your `<head>`

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
```

Or add it last in your document to enable a faster load. You then need to use document ready on your scripts so they don't run before the jQuery has been loaded.

Comment: I'm developing a jQuery plugin which will be used by others, thus I don't guarantee that the bootstrap library nor the jquery library is loaded in the targeted page, that's why I'm trying to attach them using JavaScript

Comment: And as i understand my issue is not where should to put the bootstrap library inside the document, my issue is that it doesn't see the jquery while I'm putting it inside docment.ready which guarantees the complete load of the jquery library

Comment: Well that's wired. Have you try to make console.log in your code so you can see when the progress begins to fail?